# GAE CDI jpa primefaces

Tags: google-app-engine

I would write a application with :
GAE CDI (weld) JPA JSF2 facelets primefaces.

It is possible into GAE? 
How i can use the weld on GAE?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  See:  http://java.dzone.com/articles/weld-101-runs-gae

Here's a step-by-step example (from 2010, though):  http://relation.to/Bloggers/WeldJSF20AndGoogleAppEngineNavigatingTheMinefieldPart1